# Spring boot fail to start while invoking external jar class which is xml based framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to call external jar methods from spring boot application. But the external jar is a xml based spring framework.

```
package com.ext.beans;

public class ExtBean{
    extMethod() {
     // some action
    };
}
```

**in application-context.xml**

```
<bean id="extBean" class="com.ext.beans.ExtBean" scope="prototype"/>
```

**My Spring boot application:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.ext.beans"})
public class ParentConfig {

    @Bean("extBean")
    public ExtBean extBean() {
        return new ExtBean();
    }
}

@Service
public class ParentService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("extBean")
    ExtBean extBean;
    
    public ParentServiceMethod() {
        //perform function with extBean method
        extBean.extMethod();
   }
}
```

spring boot application is fail start the application getting below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'parentService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'extBean'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'extBean' defined in class path resource [com/parent/config/ParentConfig.class]
```

*FYI: i have added the external jar dependency in spring boot pom.xml*

Answer (score 1):

On the configuration class add

```
@ImportResource({"classpath*:application-context.xml"})
```

And remove `@ComponentScan`. This annotation scan the package for annotated beans like `@Component\@Service`. And you don’t have to declare the bean in the configuration class, it will be loaded by the `@ImportResource`

I wrote an [example](https://github.com/paolopiccinini/spring-boot-starter-example) in `spring-boot-starter-example\src\main\resources` there is `application-context.xml` and in `spring-boot-consumer\src\main\java\com\example\springbootconsumer\SpringBootConsumerApplication.java` there is `@ImportResource("classpath*:application-context.xml")`

Comment: Do i need to add the full package path in ImportResource? @Pp88

Comment: Nope only the name of the xml configuration file

Comment: Issue persist. same exception application fail to start. @Pp88

Comment: @AnandKenta I've tryed and works fine. Have you put the correct file name in `@ImportResource`? The file name must be equals to the one in the jar. Also remove `@Bean` declaration in your configuration class.

Comment: can i use the @Autowired for injecting xml based bean ?

Comment: now the xml is reading but getting different error 
`application-context.xml is invalid the matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can br found for element 'http:conduit'. Caused by : java.lang.RuntimeException: org...BeanDefinitionParsingException: configuration problem: fail to import bean definition from url location [classpath*:application-context.xml]`

Comment: This is a different problem. Please ask a different question with relevant details. For example adding your application-context.xml and all relevant details

Comment: Yes you can use @Autowired for injecting the beans defined in xml.

Comment: **THE ISSUE IS RESOLVED BY ADDING LIEK THIS IN ImportResource**
`@ImportResource({"classpath*:/META-INF/spring/application-context.xml"})`
as i mentioned earlier i guess we need to add full path of xml file location. @Pp88 thanks for your support